# how to validate URL in dynamically added textbox

Tags: javascript, html

how to check URL is correct or not when i will enter into dynamically added textbox  .

here t3 is given as id of input tag but that is works only for first dynamically added textbox not for others.

how to validate another URL present into next dynamically added textbox ?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function GetDynamicTextBox(value){
return '<Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Enter the URL : </label>' +
 '<input name = "habits" type="text" id = "t3" value = "' + value + '" />' +
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" /><br><br>'
}
function AddTextBox() {
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function RemoveTextBox(div) {
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}

function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
if (values != null) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
}
}
window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
</script>



<html>
<head>
<title>T-SUMM</title>


<script type="text/javascript">

        function check()
        {
            if (document.getElementById('t1').value==""
             || document.getElementById('t1').value==undefined)
            {
                alert ("Please Enter a Query");
                return false;
            }                

            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            if(!regex .test(document.getElementById('t2').value)||!regex .test(document.getElementById('t3').value)) 
            {
                    alert("Please enter valid URL.");
                    return false;
            } 

            return true;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<form method="Post" action="./result.jsp">
<table>
<br><br><Label> Enter a Query :  &nbsp;</label>
<input name='habits' id='t1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <br><br>
<Label>     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter the URL :  </label>
<input name='habits' id='t2'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="add another URL"     onclick="AddTextBox()" /><br><br>
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
<!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return check();"> 

</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: His question is with adding the validation for dynamically added elements... Its not only about URL validation. @gyre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML - index.html

```
<html>
<head>
<title>T-SUMM</title>

<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

        function check()
        {



            if (document.getElementById('t1').value==""
             || document.getElementById('t1').value==undefined)
            {
                alert ("Please Enter a Query");
                return false;
            }                

            var regex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%!\-\/]))?/;
            var boxes = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
            for(i = 0; i < boxes.length; i++) {
                if(boxes[i].type == "text" && boxes[i].className==="urls" && !regex.test(boxes[i].value)) {
                    alert("Please enter valid URL. Error in Text Box "+boxes[i].value);
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }

    </script>

</head>
<body>

<center>
<form method="Post" action="./result.jsp">
<table>
<br><br><Label> Enter a Query :  &nbsp;</label>
<input name='habits' id='t1'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    <br><br>
<Label>     &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Enter the URL :  </label>
<input name='habits' class="urls" id='t2'>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="add another URL"     onclick="AddTextBox()" /><br><br>
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
<!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>

<input type="submit" name="submit" onclick="return check();"> 

</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

JS - script.js

```
function GetDynamicTextBox(value){
return '<Label>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Enter the URL : </label>' +
 '<input name = "habits" type="text" class="urls" value = "' + value + '" />' +
        '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="button" value="Remove" onclick = "RemoveTextBox(this)" /><br><br>'
}
function AddTextBox() {
var div = document.createElement('DIV');
div.innerHTML = GetDynamicTextBox("");
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").appendChild(div);
}

function RemoveTextBox(div) {
document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").removeChild(div.parentNode);
}

function RecreateDynamicTextboxes() {
var values = eval('<%=Values%>');
if (values != null) {
    var html = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        html += "<div>" + GetDynamicTextBox(values[i]) + "</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById("TextBoxContainer").innerHTML = html;
}
}
window.onload = RecreateDynamicTextboxes;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can first try to add an "onchange" handler to the "TextBoxContainer" div and user event.target or event.srcElement to identify whether it is a textbox that triggered the "onchange" event. If the trigger dom is exactly the ones you want, then you can try to validate its value and if it is not, you don't need to do anything. If this is done, then the rest things will be simply add/remove textboxes to the container element. Below are some sample codes that may help:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var _container = document.getElementById('TextBoxContainer');
    function add(){
        var _txt = document.createElement("INPUT");
        _txt.type = "text";
        _container.appendChild(_txt);
    }

    _container.onchange = function(event){
        var _dom = event.target || event.srcElement;
        if(_dom && _dom.tagName === "INPUT" && _dom.type === "text"){
            //alert(_dom.value);
            //You can validate the dom value here
        }
    };

    document.getElementById('add').onclick=function(){
        add();
    };
</script>
```